# Load Raw Content from Unknown Directory

Tags: c#, monogame

In my current game, modding is a HUGE part of the game. It took me a while to develop a good system of loading modded content into the game, but I finally settled on a method, and I would like to keep it if possible.

**How I'm handling modded content**

In the game's content folder (C:/Users/username/4X), there is a Mods folder. Each mod will have it's own folder inside of the Mod directory. The game goes through a file (Rather, it will. I haven't implemented it yet), and figures out which Mod directories that it's going to load. After it's figured that out, it loads all of the content into the game (I can explain in more detail if its pertinent to the topic, I just don't wan't to use up space on unnecessary things).

**So what's your problem?**

Well, the mods will all have raw resources (.fbx, .wav, .mp3), and since I can't load anything but XNB files, I have *absolutely* no idea how to load the mod's content. Well, I take it back, I've been thinking of a few solutions but I really don't know which is more practical, or if there is a better way of doing this.

First, I thought about borrowing some code from the Pipeline application, and building all of the mod's content the first time it was loaded, but I don't fully understand the Pipeline's code, and I didn't want to mess up something by partially implementing it.

Next, I thought about requiring mod creators to use the Pipeline to build their content *before* they release their mods, but that seemed kind of unprofessional, since I want to have a Mod Creation Engine that has all of the tools bundled together. Which brings me back to using some of the Pipeline's code and embedding it in the engine, but then I have the same issue as my last idea.

And finally, I thought about just loading raw content. But there's an obvious flaw with that idea.

So I guess what I'm asking is:

1. How can I load raw content? That is, content that hasn't been built into XNB Files
2. If not, how can I start learning about the code that makes the Pipeline application tick, since I'll probably have to use some of it's code?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually load some raw content directly with MonoGame. For example:

```
var texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("raw.png")`
```

should work if you've got the PNG file in the Content directory and set it's properties to Content / Copy if newer.

However, please note that this will only work for some content and some platforms. I know PNG files work, WAV files work (but they must be mono 44khz I believe) and I'm pretty sure I got MP3 files to work once.

You'll probably run into issues with FBX files and sprite fonts. There's nothing stopping you from bypassing the content manager and loading these yourself though. I've done this before with great success.

Oh, and the other thing I should mention, take a look at the [TitleContainer.OpenStream](http://www.monogame.net/documentation/?page=M_Microsoft_Xna_Framework_TitleContainer_OpenStream) method. This is a way to read a file without writing the platform specific code yourself.